# GLIBC_2.33 version in not find in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, prisma, ubuntu-22.04, prisma-binding

I recently work with Prisma for my frontend project. then I find the error.

List all commands which I run to solve the `GLIBC_2.33` error but all not working for me. if you have any suggestions tell me.

```
rajdeepsingh@officialrajdeepsingh:~/working/next-prisma$ npx prisma generate
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Error: Get Config: Unable to establish a connection to query-engine-node-api library. It seems there is a problem with your OpenSSL installation!
Details: Unable to require(`/home/rajdeepsingh/working/next-prisma/node_modules/prisma/libquery_engine-debian-openssl-3.0.x.so.node`)
 /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3)

Prisma CLI Version : 4.0.0
rajdeepsingh@officialrajdeepsingh:~/working/next-prisma$
```